# Google Calendar Python API in PI meeting location

Tags: python, google-calendar-api, raspberry-pi3

New to the PI Set up and installed the Python Quickstart on https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python?refresh=1&pli=1#troubleshooting

That works, but I need to get the location of meetings as well.

Tried altering the code

```
   for event in events:
    start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
    locations = event['location'].get('string')
    print(locations, start, event['summary'])
```

Get error keyerror 'location'

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't "Get error keyerror 'locations'" from your code because you're using "location", singular, in what you're showing

Comment: Thanks roganjosh, I miss typed the error I was getting. I edited the post to reflect the correct syntax.